# Running successive DB queries with ADODB in vba

Tags: vba, adodb

I'm pretty new to vba (like this morning), so this may very well be a dumb mistake. I'm building a macro that uses ADODB to pull info from a database and auto-populates an attached form with the info. My basic setup is below:

```
Private Sub BuildButton_Click()

'Declare Variables'
Dim con

'Connect to the Database'
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With con
    .ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQLServer;SERVER=...;database=...;"
End With

con.Open
Set result = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Defining Query Keys'
Family = "'" & FamilyBox.Value & "'"
Rating = "'" & RatingBox.Value & "'"

'SQL Queries'
Query1 = "SELECT ... "
Query2 = "SELECT ... "

'Query #1'
result.Open Query1, con

Do Until result.EOF
    Range("D4").Value = Tier(result.Fields(0).Value)
    result.MoveNext
Loop

'Query #2'
result.Open Query2, con
Do Until result.EOF
    Range("D6").Value = result.Fields(0).Value
    Range("H9").Value = result.Fields(1).Value
    Range("H8").Value = Contact(result.Fields(1).Value)
Loop
```

It works fine through the 1st query but gets caught up on the "result.Open Query2, con" line, giving an error saying:

```
Run-time error '3705'
Operation is not allowed when the object is open.
```

which makes sense to me, but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to do this.

Other things I've tried:

1. Changing "result.Open Query2, con" to "result Query2, con", which gives the error:

   ```
   Compile error:
   Expected Sub, Function, or Property
   ```
2. Adding a line "result.Close" inbetween the 2 queries so it can be opened again. This crashes the program and yields the error:

   ```
   Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
   Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed
   ```

It looks like it should be a simple fix, I've just gotten stuck. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub BuildButton_Click()

'Declare Variables'
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, result As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Family As String, Rating As String, Query1 As String, Query2 As String

'Connect to the Database'
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With con
    .ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQLServer;SERVER=...;database=...;"
End With

con.Open
Set result = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Defining Query Keys'
Family = "'" & FamilyBox.Value & "'"
Rating = "'" & RatingBox.Value & "'"

'SQL Queries'
Query1 = "SELECT ... "
Query2 = "SELECT ... "

'Query #1'
result.Open Query1, con

Do Until result.EOF
    Range("D4").Value = Tier(result.Fields(0).Value)
    result.MoveNext
Loop

result.Close
Set result = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Query #2'
result.Open Query2, con
Do Until result.EOF
    Range("D6").Value = result.Fields(0).Value
    Range("H9").Value = result.Fields(1).Value
    Range("H8").Value = Contact(result.Fields(1).Value)
Loop
```

Comment: Did you also include your 'Set result = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")' after the CLOSE, but before the open? Also, any reason why you don't want to dim the variables as the type they should be?

Comment: I did not, but just tried it and it gave the same error as without.

Comment: Can you post the actual code (minus any passwords, etc)? Sometimes there are typo's. Also, I suggest an OPTION EXPLICIT.  Where are you executing this code - Excel?

Comment: You need `result.Close` after running each query.  You  cannot call `Open` on a recordset if it's already in that state.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I'm not sure how to do post the code but it's copied and pasted so it should be fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams See "Things I've Tried" #2.

Comment: The reason for suggesting you use 'Option Explicit' is to insure (a) you have properly defined your variables, and (b) to notify you of any spelling mistakes. As for the code you posted, that is simply a snapshot in time and does not reflect the changes you made to close the recordset. You can just copy all your current code and update your question by replacing what you have there now.

Comment: Closing the recordset is required before opening another query. Try that again, and update your code with that change. Also Wayne's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Option Explicit, I didn't know that. The code is updated with what you said, but the problem was something more stupid on my part - See Answer.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Also, I updated the variables con and result with the types above, but I got a compile error along the lines of "user-defined type not defined". Are these not the correct types for these variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with adding the result.Close command between opens as said in the comments, I simply forgot the result.MoveNext in the second loop. Since result never moved to the next row, it never reached an EOF and an infinite loop resulted.

The Complete Solution:

Change:

```
'Query #1'
result.Open Query1, con

Do Until result.EOF
    Range("D4").Value = Tier(result.Fields(0).Value)
    result.MoveNext
Loop

'Query #2'
result.Open Query2, con
Do Until result.EOF
    Range("D6").Value = result.Fields(0).Value
    Range("H9").Value = result.Fields(1).Value
    Range("H8").Value = Contact(result.Fields(1).Value)
Loop
```

Into:

```
'Query #1'
result.Open Query1, con

Do Until result.EOF
    Range("D4").Value = Tier(result.Fields(0).Value)
    result.MoveNext
Loop

**result.Close**
**Set result = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")**

'Query #2'
result.Open Query2, con
Do Until result.EOF
    Range("D6").Value = result.Fields(0).Value
    Range("H9").Value = result.Fields(1).Value
    Range("H8").Value = Contact(result.Fields(1).Value)
    **result.MoveNext**
Loop
```

Comment: WHAT LINE gives the error????  I was just getting ready to say that I got your code to work. I added the 'Close' and a 'MoveNext' and defined all variables. But since your 'Range' is hard-coded, it appears you are only working with a few cells? Of sourse we have no way of knowing if you are only selecting ONE record since we can't see your SQL.  Also, did you ever try the 'Option Explicit' and compile????

Comment: None give the error now, I got it figured it out with the close and MoveNext. The range is hard-coded because the spreadsheet is a submittal form with a hundred or so fields to be filled in aesthetically, but unfortunately with no specific pattern I could loop. I did do the Option Explicit, check the last 2 comments on the question.